# Jquery UI Dialog unable to access another frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, frames

I have two frames, one on the left which searches the content of the fields in the other frame on the right. My #matchesFound div created for the dialog resides on the search frame on the right. However, the javascript that performs the search and loads the modal is on the left frame. The ending result is that the dialog is loaded on the left frame instead of the right.

Is there a way to force a jquery UI dialog to open in a specific frame? Some of the example is shaky due to explanation edits, the ajax return and serialization works fine.

```
var criteriaPage =  parent.leftSide.document;
var searchPage   =  parent.rightSide.document;
var postData     =  $(searchPage   ).serialize(); 
var matchesFound =  searchPage.getElementById('matchesFound');

var count = 
      $.ajax({        
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.url.php",
        data: postData,
        async: false
      }).responseText;

$(matchesFound).html(count);
$(matchesFound).dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    position: [350,100],
    height: 250,
    width: 400,
    modal: true
});
$(matchesFound).dialog('open');
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, this was just an issue of not accessing it with a parent level leading. Tanks for looking! The fix:

```
 var searchFrame  = parent.right;
var searchForm       = parent.sch_input.document.forms["openHouseSearch"];
var searchCriteria   = $(searchForm).serialize();
var matchesFound      =  parent.right.document.getElementById("matchesFound");

var count = 
         $.ajax({        
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.url.php",
            data: ohsData,
            async: false
         }).responseText;
searchFrame.$(matchesFound).html(count);
searchFrame.$(matchesFound).dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    height: 250,
    width: 400,
    modal: false
});
```

Comment: I still can't get the dialog to open in the second window. "searchFrame.$(matchesFound).dialog" makes no sense.